# Vue.js: vue-router subdomains

Tags: subdomain, vue.js, vue-router

The vue-router documentation does not address this topic.

Perhaps my expectation that vue-router *could* handle this illustrates a fundamental misunderstanding of mine of how subdomains operate.

Could this be handled by vue-router, and if so, how, and if not, why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, it's not possible.

`vue-router` uses [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API), which doesn't allow you to change the origin. Quote from the docs:

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
>   pushState() will throw an exception.

In other words - `vue-router` is a client-side router and you can't change the subdomain on the client-side (in the browser) without reloading the page.

Answer (score 16):

I had faced this same problem while setting up multiple subdomains for a client.

As [@mzgajner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1482553/mzgajner) mentioned it's true that it is not `directly` possible.

But I would like to show you a simple hacky configuration which can help you setup your Vue.js application work on multiple subdomains.

You can use `window.location` in javascript or HTML's `anchor tag` to redirect your app on your subdomain. And then setup your vue-router to handle new routes.

I've made [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/apal21/Vue.js-VueRouter-multiple-subdomains) which runs on 3 different subdomains.

In this GitHub repo, look at [this file](https://github.com/apal21/Vue.js-VueRouter-multiple-subdomains/blob/master/src/main.js). It shows a simple configuration to setup different routes for different subdomains.

```py
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App';
import index from './router';
import route1 from './router/route1';
import route2 from './router/route2';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const host = window.location.host;
const parts = host.split('.');
const domainLength = 3; // route1.example.com => domain length = 3

const router = () => {
  let routes;
  if (parts.length === (domainLength - 1) || parts[0] === 'www') {
    routes = index;
  } else if (parts[0] === 'route1') {
    routes = route1;
  } else if (parts[0] === 'route2') {
    routes = route2;
  } else {
    // If you want to do something else just comment the line below
    routes = index;
  }
  return routes;
};

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router(),
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App },
});
```

Hope this helps everyone!!!

Comment: And what happens if the subdomain is the name of the client's company so it would be dynamic?

Comment: I didn't get it. Can you please provide an example?

Comment: Good idea ,easy to handle also