# How to redirect in Vue.js to different url when clicked?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I'm making a post board with Vue.js and trying to make the page redirected when each post is clicked.

I've installed vue-route and axios.

In index.js,

```
export default new Router({
  route: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Post',
      component: Post
    },
    {
      path: '/:req_no',
      name: 'Detail',
      component: Detail
    },
  ]
})
```

In post.vue

```
<div @click="detailPost(post.no)">{{post.title}}</div>

.
.
.

detailPost(req_no) {
    this.$router.push({
    path: `https://dataURL/detail.php/${req_no}`
        })
      }
```

In Detail.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{contents}}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
export default {
    name: 'Datail',
    data() {
        return {
            req_no: this.$route.params.req_no,
            contents: {}
        }
    },
    created() {
      axios.get('https://dataURL/detail.php/', {
        params: {
          req_no: this.req_no
        }
      }).then(res => {
          this.contents = this.res.data
      });
    }
}
</script>
```

I'm not sure where to put the url (in the function in post.Vue, detailPost() or in Detail.vue)

If I put it in the function, I get 
`http://localhost:8080/#/http://dataURL/detail.php/2`

The API guide says I must use the params.

Could you please help me where to fix? Thanks alot!!

Comment: The simplest thing would just be to put an anchor tag and `href=yourlink`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use the router for a different domain.

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41654493/146656

What you can do is simply use vanilla JS to do it:

```js
window.location = `https://dataURL/detail.php/${req_no}`;
```

Comment: Hi @Meligy, thanks for your answer. Two more questions!
- How can I deliver params? `url/${req.no}` and `params {ruq.no : int}` seem working different...
- How can I render the page? because the URL is just data, I need to make template. 

I'm very new to Vue.js :'(. I'd be appreciated for your further answer.

Comment: For first question, you just use the same way in the answer. For second question, if the URL is just data, it means you might need to create a component to show it or something. Maybe add it to an iframe instead of redirecting to it. Depends on what this data is really, because for data usually you just make an HTTP request and render the results using a component not redirect to the URL.

Comment: I see your comment on the other answer that copied me. If it's an API, you make an AJAX request (HTTP request using JavaScript) instead of redirect to it. See the official docs here: https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 0):

Is `https://dataURL/detail.php` on same domain with your main app?

Please try:

```
this.$router.push({
  path: `/detail.php/${req_no}`
})
```

If it's different domain, you can use `window.location`

> window.location = `https://dataURL/detail.php/${req_no}`;

Comment: Hi ittus, I'm running my main app on local host. So, your advice seems not working :'(. Any other recommendation?

Comment: If it's the same domain, can you change `dataURL` to `localhost:8080`, too, because it makes confuse between `dataURL` and `localhost:8080`.

Comment: Thank you for the further answer. The thing is the url is API. So I have to template the data..and also how can I pass params if I use `window.location`? Thanks again!