# How to redirect to an external file with Vue Router

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router

I have a website developed with VueJS using Vue Router in the domain "site.com". And I also have a blog developed with wordpress that is in a subdomain "blog.site.com".

And it was requested to me to change the blog access URL to "site.com/blog". But I have no idea of how to link a vue route to a wordpress blog.

Is that possible? 
Anyone have any idea of how to do that? 
Maybe via my .htaccess?

PS.: I tried loading the blog html via a request using axios and render it in a vue component, but the performance was not good enough, so this is not a possibility.

Comment: hi you can check this links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654181/vue-js-vue-router-subdomains

Comment: Is that a single or two separate http servers?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can't. Vue-Router works on browser state and can't go anywhere else. But you can use this practice if it's best or not:

- Create a component for your links
- Check if the target is external or not. You can do that by comparing the target to current URL.
- Use `v-if` and `v-else` to create `router-link` or simple anchor tag based on the above result

Hope this helps you.