# Rails backend / Vue 3 Frontend - Handle subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, vue-router

i'm currently building a multitenant SaaS application with Rails 7.

I started using rails as a monolith application without caring so much about frontend, the problem is that step by step it's getting bigger and bigger and i think it would be worth to split the backend and fronted to have a Rails REST API application and a Vue 3 app as frontend using vue-router

The problem that now i'm facing is this:

How can i handle different subdomains? I will explain myself better:

- Every subdomain ('subdomain.example.com') will search for the correct tenant looking based on the subdomain
- If the subdomain is 'www' or there's no subdomain then the landing page / blog will be shown
- Possibly i would expand the check on a possible second subdomain (client.subdomain.example.com) this will be needed for a Cloudflare for SaaS configuration when it occurs to bind a client own domain (clientdomain.com) to my application

I've looked for a while and the only solution i found out is:
[Vue.js: vue-router subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41654181/vue-js-vue-router-subdomains)

so i tried to adapt it to my needs with something like this inside my main.js:

```
const app = createApp(App)

const host = window.location.host;
const parts = host.split('.');
const domainLength = 3; // route1.example.com => domain length = 3

const router = () => {
    let routes;
    console.log(parts[0] === 'www')
    if (parts[0] === 'www') {
    console.log('landing')
    routes = landing_router;
    } else if (parts.length === (domainLength - 1) && parts[0] != 'www') {
        console.log('dashboard')
        routes = dashboard_router;
    } else {
        console.log('landing')
        routes = landing_router;
    } 

    return routes;
};


app.use(createPinia())
app.use(router())

app.mount('#app')
```

And then i created 2 different routers (i'm not handling the third point of the list yet)

Is this solution good? Is there a better way to do it? Or should i drop the idea and stick to rails?